# Retrieving an array from Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, swift3, pfquery, back4app

I am trying to download an array from Back4Apps.com (Parse.com equivalent).  The below displays no errors, but when it gets to the line "downloadQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in", it simply skips over the rest of the code to the end of the function.

- I have tested the "username" and it seems to be correct.
- I am certain the class and subClass names are correct.
- The parse parameters are correct and I already have many other parse functions working.

Any suggestions where to look?

```
var userCommonNameArray = [String]()
var userCommonNameESArray = [String]()
var userCommonNameFRArray = [String]()
var userCommonNameDEArray = [String]()
var speciesNameArray = [String]()
var userNotesArray = [String]()


    func insertFromParse () {

        let username = userDefault.value(forKey: "username") as! String

        let downloadQuery = PFQuery(className:"ReefLifeApps")
        downloadQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)



//    This is there Xcode skips from to the end
//    tried variations of the below line.  Neither worked.            
//      downloadQuery.findObjectsInBackground {(objects, error) -> Void in
        downloadQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

            if error == nil {
                // Do something with the found objects
                for object in objects! {

                    self.userCommonNameArray.append(object.object(forKey: "userCommonName") as! String)
                    self.userCommonNameESArray.append(object.object(forKey: "userCommonNameES") as! String)
                    self.userCommonNameFRArray.append(object.object(forKey: "userCommonNameFR") as! String)
                    self.userCommonNameDEArray.append(object.object(forKey: "userCommonNameDE") as! String)
                    self.speciesNameArray.append(object.object(forKey: "speciesName") as! String)
                    self.userNotesArray.append(object.object(forKey: "userNotes") as! String)

                }
            } else {

                print("Error: \(error!)")
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: when you say "it skips over", are you watching execution line by line in the debugger?   the find runs async, you won't see execution enter there unless you set a breakpoint inside the block.

Comment: Yes, I was watching the execution line by line in the debugger.  I used the Step Into during this process and it did not reach the "if error == nil" line.  Do you have any suggestions how to dig dipper?

Comment: sure.  set a breakpoint *inside* the completion block.  then resume execution at full speed.   the idea is that find runs after the current run loop returns.  you'll only execute the completion after a round trip on the network is done, which is much later than when the debugger runs the findObjects function.

Comment: if seems you are right.  The data was actually downloading, but the error was just after this function as when I tested if array.count > 0, this is what was broken.  Thank you